# Small powdery white around bottom of stems of a Peace Lily, and some brown lesions on some of the leaves

Tags: pests, fungus, peace-lily

**Problems:**

1. I recently noticed some small powdery white regions around the bottom of some of the stems on my peace lily, below are some examples:

[image: Example powdery white region]

[image: Another example powdery white region]

They become less prominent when wet, but are visible again immediately after the regions dry out.

2. I'm not sure it's a related issue, but some of the leaves on my peace lily have lots of small, dry, brown lesions.  Not all leaves seem to have these, they seem to only be common on the larger leaves.  They have had them for a while, below is an example:
   [image: Example leave with lots of small, dry, brown lesions]

**How I have investigated the problem:**

- I inspected the other stems and leaves of the plant, but did not really see anything that looked unusual.  I wasn't able to find any abnormalities on the underside of any leaves, which I believe is a typical symptom of powder fungus (which from what I've read online, is what this sounds like it could be).
- I had a look on various websites and have googled the symptoms, but was unable to find any articles or videos which included pictures of the described (but similar-sounding problems).  It appears to be quite hard to find satisfactory, actionable articles about peace lilies, many seem to contradict each other and do not seem to contain meaningful conclusions or related pictures.  I would very much appreciate some advice on where I can find good articles for problems like the one I have described.  rhs.org.uk looks promising, but the search function doesn't seem to work particularly well.

**How I take care of my peace lily:**

- I water it with roughly 1 litre of filtered water, whenever the deeper soil feels dry and the plant is drooping.  I make sure that the pot has finished draining, before I put it back in its planter.  I normally do this every 1-2 weeks.
- I keep it in a relatively bright room, but it doesn't receive direct sunlight.  On most days, it measures around 2,000-8,000 lux near to the plant.
- It is not particularly humid in the room (~37% rh).
- I rarely clean the leaves, so dust does accumulate on them.
- It sits next to a similarly sized anthurium, which doesn't appear to have any visible fungus or pests.
- It is kept in a relatively drafty room, but is not directly exposed to the drafts.
- I do not mist the peace lily (I probably should, but I have not found it to make much of a difference in similar environments in the past).
- I do not move it around very often.

Please advise.